# Issue with Anaconda package manager - library installed, but not found in Spyder

Tags: python, anaconda, package, spyder

I installed cairo using Anaconda Navigator (in case it's important, cairo is also installed in the other two environments: miniconda3 and spyder-env):
[image: cairo is installed]

I launch Spyder from Anaconda Navigator, and try to import cairo, and get an error saying:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cairo'
[image: no module named 'cairo']

Spyder seems to be using the correct python environment. If I run `conda list cairo', I get the following output:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you do `conda list` from Spyder terminal? Are you able to locate cairo?

Comment: @mmustafaicer yes, if i type `conda list` in the Spyder terminal, I see: cairo                     1.16.0               h691a603_2

Comment: You can investigate Tools > PYTHONPATH manager and if necessary add path to "C:\Users\xxxx\lib\site-packages" manually where your cairo.py is installed.

Comment: I tried this on my mac, I added the path to where cairo is installed, but I still get the same error.

Comment: `pip install pycairo` worked for me. Can you try that? [https://pypi.org/project/pycairo/](https://pypi.org/project/pycairo/).

Comment: @mmustafaicer oh that's closer! I now have a new error: ImportError: dlopen(/Users/xxxx/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cairo/_cairo.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_cairo_tee_surface_add'

Comment: @dpholmes, unfortunately you ran the wrong command, which is the cause of the error you reported. That's because pip and conda packages are binary incompatible and so they can't be mixed for the most part. Please run now `pip uninstall pycairo` and then `conda install pycairo`. If you're still getting the same error, I'm afraid you'll have to reinstall Anaconda because you broke it by running `pip install cairo`.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba THANK YOU! This solved the problem - please post it as an answer so I can Accept it. Seriously, thank you, I was about to give up. I am ignorant to the way `pip` and `conda` work, thanks for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 1):

I had problem similar to this with VaderSentiment analysis library. Jupyter notebook couldn't find it although it was installed. Either you can use a more stable Python version such as Python 3.7 for compatibility or you can use `importlib`.

```bash
conda install python=3.7
```

I solved it using [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) This does not answer your question "what am i doing wrong", but it solved the problem in my case. Just locate cairo.py in your Anaconda folder whatever the environment is. You can make necessary adjustments. I hope this helps if you have emergency to use that package.

```py
import importlib.util
import sys
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("vaderSentiment", r"C:\Users\matt\Anaconda3\envs\sentiment\Lib\site-packages\vaderSentiment\vaderSentiment.py")
foo = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules["vaderSentiment"] = foo
spec.loader.exec_module(foo)
```